# Unable to toggle LED through AJAX request to Arduino

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to toggle an LED through a button in the web server created by the ESP8266. But when I click the button nothing is happening. The Arduino code is perfect. something is wrong with the HTML and/or JS code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script          
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".led").click(function() {
          var p = $(this).attr('id');                                                               
          $.get("http://192.168.4.1:80/", { pin: p }); // Sending the get request
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <head>
    <title>Home Automation System</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="13" class="led">Toggle Pin 13</button> 
  </body>
</html>
```

The below code is the original code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ESP8266 LED Control</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="13" class="led">Toggle Pin 13</button>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".led").click(function(){
                var p = $(this).attr('id');

                $.get("http://192.168.4.1:80/", {pin:p});
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have two `<head>` elements in your HTML. Move the `<title>` in to the first one and remove the second. Also, check the console for errors with the AJAX request.

Comment: You're missing a `</script>`

Comment: ...and an unclosed `<script>` tag.

Comment: Side note: `$(this).attr("id")` is too much jQuery IMO when you can simply do `this.id` instead.

Comment: Try adding in `.ajaxError()` to see if the problem is with your AJAX call. (Info on using that error handler [here](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/).)

Answer (score 0):

1. `script` tag is not a self closing tag. A closing `</script>` is needed.
2. `head` tag should be only one.

Check this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script          
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".led").click(function() {
          var p = $(this).attr('id');                                                               
          $.get("http://192.168.4.1:80/", { pin: p }); // Sending the get request
        });
      });
    </script>
    <title>Home Automation System</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="13" class="led">Toggle Pin 13</button> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please describe in detail everything that you changed, and why, so that the OP understands exactly what was wrong. "Try this" isn't a good answer description.

Comment: Still not working. I am trying this on my mobile and still not able to toggle.

Comment: The original code contained this line "<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>". Hence i had to save a javascript library jquery. And tried it on my mobile which did not work. So i thought of adding a jquery link instead of storing the jquery file in the same directory which contais the html code

Comment: what error did you get? If you save those codes to a html file and visit it in browser, you will see it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should check a little about `AJAX` and `XML` communication between `client`(browser) and `server`(board).

There is a working project with `AJAX` and `XML` made by Ray Burnette: [link](https://www.hackster.io/rayburne/esp8266-webserver-using-javascript-and-xml-aa78f1)
It controls the delay rate of an output pin through a range type input. You can modify the code to suit your needs.